# Why does this give junk value?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, garbage

I am getting garbage / junk values as output when my program is run and the data displayed.

Why is it so?

Can someone help me to understand how to properly pass by pointers and not get junk values?

This program is about stack creation of `struct books` type variables.

By default shouldn't the variable `bks` pass by pointer and change when `b` is changed?

`bks` is still storing garbage value.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct books
{
    int yrpub;
    char name[100],author[50];
};
int top=-1;
int push(struct books b[],int top,int n)
{
    if(top==n-1)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        ++(top);
        printf("Enter books info: \n");
        printf("Enter name: ");
        gets(b[top].name);
        printf("Enter author: ");
        gets(b[top].author);
        printf("Enter Year of publish: ");
        scanf("%d",&b[top].yrpub);
        return top;
    }
}
void display(struct books b[],int top)
{
    int i;
    if(top==-1)
        printf("No books in the stack...");
    for(i=0;i<=top;i++)
    {
        printf("Details of book %d: \n",i+1);
        printf("Name: %s\nAuthor: %s\nYear of publish: %d\n",b[i].name,b[i].author,b[i].yrpub);
    }
    system("pause");
}

int main()
{
    struct books bks[10];
    int ch;
    system("cls");
    printf("Select an option:\n");
    printf("1. Push book\n2. Pop book\n3. Peep book\n4. Display all books info\n5. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter a choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    fflush(stdin);
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        top=push(bks,top,10);
        break;

    case 4:
        system("cls");
        display(bks,top);
        break;

    case 5:     exit(0);

    default:    printf("\nWrong choice...Please retry.");
        long i,j;
        for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
            for(j=0;j<100;j++);
    }
    main();
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` may be undefined behavior

Comment: If this is C++ code, then calling `main` is undefined behavior.

Comment: A global variable called `top` and a function parameter called `top` is a recipe for confusion.  Use `-Wshadow` if you compile with gcc to warn you of such problems. Unless you're running on Windows, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sorry my bad... I removed C++ tag... However even if I create a new function without having the need to call main, it still gives garbage value...

Comment: Yes, I am using Dev-cpp in Windows... and I have used fflush(stdin) so that the '\n' entered during the choice does go into the name part if I push new book into stack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you recursively call `main()`, you create a new array `bk`.

The information you entered in the previous invocation of `main()` is hidden from the new one.

- *To iterate is human; to recurse, divine.*

In this context, give up divinity for humanity. Use iteration — in this context it is better.

This is your primary problem; there may also be other off-by-one or other errors.

Comment: Actually the question mentions the use of functions only so I need to pass the stack array to the function and maintain it... Isn't there a way out of this other than iterations?

Comment: You could, but probably shouldn't, make `bk` into a global array.  You can certainly pass the array of structures to functions — you already do.  Iterating is most sensible here.

Answer (score 0):

```
push:
if(top==n-1)
        return -1;
main:
top=push(bks,top,10);
```

`top` is reset when the stack is **full**

Edit:
And the second problem is `main` being called again, `struct books bks[10]` is reset in the next `main`, it is a **recursion**. Declare `bks` as global or go with a `while` loop instead of recursion.

```
while (1) {
    getChoices();
    if (exit)
        /* exit from here */
    process();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a problem, but my main question is if even I add only 1 book details even then when I am displaying the details it is giving garbage values...

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer... Since I cannot use recursion since questions explicitly mentions use of functions, I made bks static and it solved my problems... thanks.